# Composer in Docker not passing verification for private repo

Tags: git, docker, ssl, ssh, composer-php

I have a Docker container which is bringing up a project which has dependencies in a private repo.

`Dockerfile` is copying my passwordless SSH keys (permissions are `600` & `644`):

```
COPY docker/config/id_rsa /root/.ssh/
COPY docker/config/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/
```

After copying, Composer dependencies are getting installed:

```
RUN echo *** >> /etc/hosts \
  && composer config -a -g *URL *USER *PASS \
  && composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress
```

At the same time I have deleted `composer.lock` to make sure nothing is left from previous installs.

Repositories part from composer looks like this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@***:***/libs/***.git",
        "options": {
            "ssl": {
                "local_cert": "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
            }
        }
    },
],
```

And during the creation of container I am getting an error saying:

```
[RuntimeException]
Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@***:***/libs/***.git' '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/.../'
Cloning into bare repository '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/...'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Repository does indeed exist, SSH keys are valid, and strangest of all...if I omit the `composer install` command and enter the created container, change nothing and do it manually from terminal, it installs everything.

**EDIT:**

I have also tried manually in the `RUN` command writing the keys if by any case they weren't available during the container creation, but that didn't help.

I have also tried removing `"options"` section from Composer

Comment: How is the `id_rsa.pem` generated? You copy only the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`

Comment: Sorry, it is supposed to be `id_rsa.pub`. It is generated with ssh keygen. Both are copied

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+Host+key+verification+failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was missing were these parts in the `RUN` command:

```
echo "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx my_server_name" >> /etc/hosts

ssh-keyscan -t rsa my_server_name >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Once that was done I could omit `"options"` section completely from Composer